# ¿Cómo abro un fragment con un ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, fragment

Tengo una duda sobre mi código, estoy intentando abrir un `Fragment` con un `ImageButton`, desde una clase que no es **ActivityMain**.

```
public class calentamiento extends Fragment {

ImageButton Boton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_caminar, container, false);
```

El `findViewById` no me lo reconoce:

```
    Boton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.boton1);

    Boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

La clase "calentamiento" que es la local, me esta dando error:

```
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(calentamiento.this, Caminar.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }

    });
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Es **"Boton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.boton1);"**.

Comment: Y creo que la clase calentamiento te esta dando error por que no es una **Activity**, es un **Fragment** que se hereda de la **Activity**, por lo tanto deberias poner es el nombre de la **Activity Padre** que contiene a tu `Fragment` y ahí si te mandaría a la otra clase.

Comment: @ChechoParrado estos comentarios en realidad son lo que soluciona el problema, porque no agregaste respuesta? :|

Comment: Jajaja que tal @Jorgesys, se me paso por alto. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente para obtener la referencia del botón dentro de la vista que lo contiene, lo debes realizar mediante `view.findViewById()` ya que `view` es la vista que inflas y debe contener el botón. Es importante que el botón con id `boton1` se encuentre dentro de `fragment_caminar.xml`:

```
 //Boton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.boton1); 
 Boton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.boton1);
```

Segundo, no puiedes usar `calentamiento.this` como contexto ya que estas dentro de un `Fragment`, usa el contexto de la Activity que contiene el Fragment, `getActivity()`:

```
// Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(calentamiento.this, Caminar.class);
Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), Caminar.class);
```

La clase corregida sería:

```
 public class calentamiento extends Fragment {

    ImageButton Boton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_caminar, container, false);

        Boton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.boton1);

        Boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), Caminar.class);
                startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
            }

        });
        return view;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, de esta manera ya no me manda error el código, el único inconveniente, es que al momento de emular la aplicación, se detiene y no abre. ¿Esto a que se puede deber?

Answer (score 0):

Crea una variable global.

```
private View rootView = null;
```

Retorna dicha View en el onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Inflate the layout for this fragment
   rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_caminar, container, false);    

actualizar();
return rootView;
}
```

Crea una función para actualizar tus componentes

```
private void actualizar(){
    Boton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.boton1);

Boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(calentamiento.this, Caminar.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }

    });

}
```